# def cylinder_vol is not giving a correct output

Tags: python

```py
def cylinder_vol(base_radius, height):
    volume = base_radius**2 * height
    return volume
    
print(cylinder_vol(29.5,.8))
```

the output is not correct

```
[RULE] The `cylinder_vol` function should be defined in the `task3a.py` file with the `base_radius` and `height`
| parameters.
[RESULT] PASSED (1/1)
[FEEDBACK] Great work! Your `cylinder_vol` has been declared correctly.
----------
[RULE] The `cylinder_vol` function should return the expected values to the provided testing input.
[RESULT] FAILED (0/1)
[FEEDBACK] The expected output to the provided arguments (1.8789443299315256, 44.488282318737305) is 493.4275. Your
| implementation of `cylinder_vol` returned 157.0628.
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: def cylinder_vol(base_radius, height):
    volume = base_radius**2 * height
    return volume
    
print(cylinder_vol(29.5,.8))

Comment: Shouldn't the volume of a cylinder involve Pi somehow?

Comment: Scott, I had it with the implementation of pi but it came back as wrong. My feedback is telling me the coding I am using is correct but the output is wrong.

Comment: How can the coding be "correct" if the output is wrong?  Maybe you *should* be using Pi, but did so incorrectly?  Hard to say, since you didn't show how you tried to use it.

Comment: It's wrong because your calculation for Volume is wrong. Volume of a cylinder is pi * (r**2) * height. We'd be happy to help, but getting the formula for volume of a cylinder is minimal effort on your part. This isn't a coding question.

Comment: def cylinder_vol(base_radius, height):
    volume = (4/3) * pi * (radius ** 2)
    return volume
    
print(cylinder_vol(29.5,.8))

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly the volume of a cylinder is `pi*(r^2)*h`. In your function you forgot to multiply the result by pi.

Here's the corrected version of your function:

```py
# the pi constant belongs to the module math.py
from math import pi

def cylinder_vol(base_radius, height):
    volume = pi * base_radius ** 2 * height
    return volume
```

Comment: bdollu, I think I know what I did wrong. I didn't have pi * base radius **, I only had base_radius ** 2 * height! I am an idiot. Thank you so much. I feel foolish for not catching that.

Comment: Don't worry, even expert programmers make such silly mistakes sometimes. As you become more experienced, your debugging skills improve, and you will be able to diagnose and fix such bugs faster.

Comment: You may want to mark this answer as accepted. To do so, click on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, you'd need to use `pi` in order to calculate the volume of a cylinder.

```
import math
def cylinder_vol(base_radius, height):
    volume = math.pi * (base_radius**2) * height
    return volume
    
# Using your test example that caused the failure.
print(cylinder_vol(1.8789443299315256, 44.488282318737305)) # -> 493.4275
```

I'll try to explain in detail what's going on here and hopefully it clears any ambiguity you're experiencing.

When the feedback from the question say it's "declared correctly" they're essentially saying it ***looks correct***. And in some way it does, it accepts two argument and returns some value. This is the thing about programming - things can ***look right*** but ***behave wrongly***.

In this case, the volume is calculated wrongly due to a formula error.

Next, why `import math`? `math` is a built-in library. You can imagine there'd be many things that people want to do that they'd want to reuse. Rather than have everyone code out what `pi` is you could store them in a library like `math`. When someone needs to use mathematical functionalities, they could `import` the library and use it.

Comment: I understand that it will take minimal effort on my part, I am not sure why its so confusing to me. I get the formulas I need to use but its confusing with the program we are using to learn and the way they want everything set up.

Comment: @thestruggleisreal I've updated for brevity. Hope this clears any confusion

Comment: I appreciate it. That make sense. I didn't want to touch the formula because it kept saying did it right but I knew for a fact it was incorrect. I had imported math and from math import pi earlier in the code. I had to do three other parts before getting to this part, thats why I didn't have it included.